# Quickest method for matching nested XML data against database table structure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, data-structures, orm

I have an application which creates `datarequests` which can be quite complex. These need to be stored in the database as tables. An outline of a `datarequest` (as XML) would be...

```
<datarequest>
  <datatask view="vw_ContractData" db="reporting" index="1">
    <datefilter modifier="w0">
      <filter index="1" datatype="d" column="Contract Date" param1="2009-10-19 12:00:00" param2="2012-09-27 12:00:00" daterange="" operation="Between" />
    </datefilter>
    <filters>
      <alternation index="1">
        <filter index="1" datatype="t" column="Department" param1="Stock" param2="" operation="Equals" />
      </alternation>
      <alternation index="2">
        <filter index="1" datatype="t" column="Department" param1="HR" param2="" operation="Equals" />
      </alternation>
      </filters>
    <series column="Turnaround" aggregate="avg" split="0" splitfield="" index="1">
      <filters />
    </series>
    <series column="Requested 3" aggregate="avg" split="0" splitfield="" index="2">
      <filters>
        <alternation index="1">
          <filter index="1" datatype="t" column="Worker" param1="Malcom" param2="" operation="Equals" />
        </alternation>          
      </filters>
    </series>
    <series column="Requested 2" aggregate="avg" split="0"  splitfield="" index="3">
      <filters />
    </series>
    <series column="Reqested" aggregate="avg" split="0" splitfield="" index="4">
      <filters />
    </series>
  </datatask>
</datarequest>
```

This encodes a datarequest comprising a daterange, main filters, series and series filters. Basically any element which has the `index` attribute can occur multiple times within its parent element - the exception to this being the `filter` within `datefilter`.

But the structure of this is kind of academic, the problem is more fundamental:

When a request comes through, XML like this is sent to SQLServer as a parameter to a stored proc. This XML is shredded into a de-normalised table and then written iteratively to normalised tables such as `tblDataRequest (DataRequestID PK)`, `tblDataTask`, `tblFilter`, `tblSeries`. This is fine.

The problem occurs when I want to **match a given XML defintion with one already held in the DB**. I currently do this by...

- Shredding the XML into a de-normalised table
- Using a CTE to pull *all the existing data* in the database into that same de-normalised form
- Matching using a huge `WHERE` condition (34 lines long)

..This will return me any DataRequestID which exactly matches the XML given. I fear that this method will end up being painfully slow - partly because I don't believe the CTE will do any clever filtering, it will pull all the data every single time *before* applying the huge `WHERE`.

I have thought there must be better solutions to this eg

- When storing a `datarequest`, also store a hash of the datarequest somehow and simply match on that. In the case of collision, use the current method. I wanted however to do this using set-logic. And also, I'm concerned about irrelevant small differences in the XML changing the hash - spurious spaces etc.
- Somehow perform the matching iteratively from the bottom up. Eg produce a list of filters which match on the lowest level. Use this as part of an `IN` to match Series. Use this as part of an `IN` to match DataTasks etc etc. The trouble is, I start to black-out when I think about this for too long.

**Basically - Has anyone ever encountered this kind of problem before (they must have). And what would be the recommended route for tackling it?** example (pseudo)code would be great :)

Comment: I managed the issue similar to this using XML normalization (trimming and sorting nodes) and hashes. It worked pretty well and fast. So it was parsing XML first, applying a normalization and then calculate hash in general way.

Comment: @ViktorStolbin Thanks for your comment. So there is hope for me! I won't need to sort nodes as order is important - although, attribute order is not. Did you sort attribute order?

Comment: I was sorting everything due XML was a straightforward representation of DB query and I relied on the DB query optimization there.

Comment: One thing. Possibly hash implementation should be sensitive to the elements order.

Comment: Apparently SQLServer XML type [cannot be trusted to preserve attribute order.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187107%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) I may need to sort my XML at application-side before passing as `VARCHAR` to stored-procedure.

Comment: Basically to match 2 data-sets, you need to either convert one data-set to be equivalent to the other one's structure .. or define an isometric matching method

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer Since asking this question I have solved the problem by taking the input (XML) - `SELECT`ing from that `FOR XML` - This will make SQLServer put the XML into its 'form' - regardless of how the input was formatted. This means I can safely hash knowing that input attribute order is not important as SQLServer will force the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the possibility of minor variances, I'd run the request through an XML transform (XSLT).

Alternatively, since you've already got the code to parse this out into a denormalized staging table that's fine too. I would then simply using [FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) to create a new XML doc.

Your goal here is to create a standardized XML document that respects ordering where appropriate and removes inconsistencies where it is not.

Once that is done, store this in a new table. Now you can run a direct comparison of the "standardized" request XML against existing data.

To do the actual comparison, you can use a hash, store the XML as a string and do a direct string comparison, or do a full XML comparison like this: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10317/xquery-lab-36-writing-a-tsql-function-to-compare-two-xml-values-part-2.aspx

My preference, as long as the XML is never over 8000bytes, would be to create a unique string (either VARCHAR(8000) or NVARCHAR(4000) if you have special character support) and create a unique index on the column.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer Rai! Welcome to SO. This method is incidentally pretty much how I have solved the problem!