# Normalising XML in SQLServer for hashing

Tags: .net, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005, xml-parsing

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12674327/395628) which led me to do the following.

- Create an XML representation of a C# object structure in order to pass it to SQLServer.
- Create a stored procedure which *hashes the XML* and then shreds the XML into related tables and also stores the hash in the root table for quick lookup.

This means that I can pass complex object data to SQLServer and do a lookup on the hash rather than trying to shred and match the XML against the tables (which I can also do but is slow(er))...

However - One of the nice things about XML is that you can format it eg indent it etc - and also - that attribute order is not important. BUT when you hash something formatting and indentation IS important. So what I do in C# is...

- Normalise the XML by putting all attributes in alphabetical order
- use .ToString(DisableFormatting) to remove extra formatting spaces

This works fine, but when I'm testing it's easier to have *formatted* XML so I can see more easily what I'm passing to the stored proc.

It would be nice if SQLServer could be trusted to preserve attribute order [but it can't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187107%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)...

> The order of attributes in an XML instance is not preserved. When you
>   query the XML instance stored in the xml type column, the order of
>   attributes in the resulting XML may be different from the original XML
>   instance.

This means that I can't use SQLServer's XML datatype to normalise the data.

What bothers me is that at some point someone will be using my procs and think "oh great, XML, attribute order doesn't matter, formatting doesn't matter, *the data represented is the same*" However, when I hash this isn't going to be the case.

Anyone got any solutions to this problem? I don't really want to write an XML parser in T-SQL!! Or use an XML parser someone else has written in order to normalise it. Why can't the SQLServer XML datatype just preserve attribute order?

I suppose I can "trust" my app to always pass XML in the same format/order thus resulting in the same hash for the same object. But I'm uncomfortable with the idea that the stored proc has to also "trust" the app to do this. I would like to somehow be able to check the normalisation of the XML, it will obviously be more robust like that.

Comment: Although the results of the SQL Server parse/normalise process may not create exactly the same XML as c#, it is at least consistent. Can you not rely on this consistency to process your XML before hashing it?

Comment: @paul Well for my actual application purposes yes. But if someone wants to see if a particular record exists and they call the proc manually, or from another application, with some *formatted* XML then they may think it doesn't when it actually does, and then I could end up with two semantically identical record with different hashes - which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to serialize the object inside the store procedure.

Let's supose the following class:

```
class MyCustomObject 
{
    int id;
    string SomeField;
}
```

Then you can use a store procedure where you serialize the object in xml and calculate the checksum of the input parameters, then in another one you can pass a HashValue(checksum) and a Xml. By deserializing the Xml yo can calculate the checksum of the fields in the Xml and compare it with the passed HashValue.

Try this code:
(Note you should store the hash value and return it to caller and do something with the xml)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE HashObject(@id int, @SomeField varchar(255)) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CHECKSUM(@id, @SomeField) AS CalculatedHashValue,
        (SELECT @id AS ID, @SomeField AS SomeField FOR XML RAW('xmlRowName')) AS Xml_Data,
        @id AS SPCall_ID,
        @SomeField AS SPCall_SomeField
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE CheckHash(@HashValue INT, @data XML) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  
        CHECKSUM(rt.value('@ID', 'int'), rt.value('@SomeField', 'varchar(255)')) AS Xml_CalculatedHashValue,
        @data Xml_Data,
        rt.value('@ID', 'int') AS Xml_ID,
        rt.value('@SomeField', 'varchar(255)') AS Xml_SomeField,
        @HashValue AS SPCall_HashValue

    FROM @data.nodes('xmlRowName') AS nd(rt)

END
GO

DECLARE @id INT = 11
DECLARE @SomeField varchar(255) = 'string value'
DECLARE @data XML

EXEC dbo.HashObject @id, @SomeField

SET @data = (SELECT @id AS ID, @SomeField AS SomeField FOR XML RAW('xmlRowName'))
EXEC dbo.CheckHash 0, @data

SET @data = (SELECT 25 AS ID, 'diferent string value' AS SomeField FOR XML RAW('xmlRowName'))
EXEC dbo.CheckHash 0, @data
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure how I would apply this solution to my situation (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674327/quickest-method-for-matching-nested-xml-data-against-database-table-structure)) - where I can have my inner elements repeating any number of times. I need to pass the data from .Net to SQLServer as XML but I want the attribute order and formatting to be irrelevant to the hash value.